# Changing stored database date to current timezone (strtotime?)

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone

When adding a record to a database, I use the MySQL `NOW()` function to date-stamp a column. However, my server is situated halfway around the world, and has a different timezone to me.

When pulling this date-stamp out of the database, I need to adjust it's value by +8 hours in order to have it display the "correct" time on my site. However, I need to `strtotime` it to create a useable date in the first place, then `strtotime` it to +8 hours, then `strtotime` it to change it tothe required format, right?

I've tried multiple iterations of statements, but I can either get `30 Sep 07:35` or `01 Jan 00:00` results, and not the requested `30 Sep 15:35`.

The value is stored in the database in `datetime` format: `2014-09-30 07:35:36`

One of the many things I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
$chat_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($chat_time));
$chat_time = strtotime("+8 hours");
$chat_time = date("d M, H:i", strtotime($chat_time));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) to adjust the timezone for the datetime value:

```
$chat_time = new DateTime($chat_time, new DateTimeZone('DB_TIMEZONE'));
$chat_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('YOUR_TIMEZONE'));
echo $chat_time->format("d M, H:i");
```

Obviously you need to replace `DB_TIMEZONE` and `YOUR_TIMEZONE` with valid values. You can get a list of them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Answer (score 1):

You better set timezone on your connection, `NOW()` and likes will then return the correct one:

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
```

That's an sql query. You need to execute it after connecting.

Sure, this is only for new inserts and updates, you need to fix also existing:

```
UPDATE table SET datetimeColumn = DATE_ADD(datetimeColumn, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
```

Comment: A great idea to prevent this problem in the future, thanks. +1

Comment: Instead of setting the connection to the local timezone, I suggest saving timestamps in UTC to remove the ambiguity. Use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()` for that.